# Convert static type to string in C++ with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, typeof

This is the same question as [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c) but I don't want RTTI. I'm writing code with expression templates (e.g. Eigen), which means the types of my variables can be really involved and that I don't know the actual types. However, the compiler knows the types and can tell me when something goes wrong:

```
error: ‘const struct Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1> >’ ...
```

Is there any way I can convert a variable name to a string with the (static) type name so that I could debug the program without breaking it? E.g.

```
int a;
M b;
cout << TYPEOF(a) << endl << TYPEOF(b) << endl;
```

would print

```
int
const struct Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1> >’
```

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001207/compile-time-typeid-without-rtti-with-gcc

Comment: @John Not really duplicate: this question is more of a follow-up on the other question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Please check again what question I linked to.

Comment: @John I did. Look at the answers. In fact, the accepted answer directly says that you need some Macro fluff to solve this – which leads us here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm sorry, I don't understand what part of this question is not covered by a combination of the one linked by the OP and the question I linked to?

Comment: @John Well, how do you do it then?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't, but if I did, I would either accept that I have to use the type-info system (as described in the question OP linked to), or I would use something like the `REFLECTION_REGISTER_TYPE` macro that is described in the question I linked to.

Comment: @John My apologies, I indeed overlooked that addition to the *question*. Yes, that indeed answers this one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No problem. And I apologise for dismissing your original comment.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew: Since I'm debugging, I accept that I have to use the type-info system. But, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001243/1693829 basically says that the compiler knows the static type but I have no way of stringifying it.

Comment: @Mankka: You do have a way of stringifying it, using type-info, as described in answers to the question you linked to. It's unfortunate that that way is tied to the language's RTTI system, but as noted in ecatmur's answer below, there isn't necessarily any runtime overhead for this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeid` can be applied to a type (5.2.8p4):

```
std::cout << typeid(int).name() << '\n'
  << typeid(M).name() << '\n';
```

This doesn't involve any run-time overhead.

Answer (score 3):

std::cout << typeid(int).name() << '\n'
  << typeid(M).name() << '\n';

Answer (score 1):

I marked https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703184/1693829 as the answer, thank you! This is a wrapper that I wrote:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string t2s(T tt) {
  char *name;
  int status;
  name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(tt).name(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::string namestring(name);
  free(name);
  return namestring;
}
```